# How can I make a drop down list reference different data when an option is selected?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I followed a tutorial to create a drop down list in MS Excel, but it doesn't quite do what I want it to.
I have two worksheets, "Main" and "FooBars". FooBars structured like so:

[image]

My drop down list in Main gets its data from FooBars. The group of list options is named "FooBars" which references `='FooBars'!$B$2:$B$3`, and the cell in Main that shows it has data validation's source set to `=FooBars`.

In my drop down list, it displays Bar options as needed.
However, when an option is selected, is there a way to have it fill the cell in with the corresponding Foo data instead?

**Example:**
When the user clicks the drop down list and selects "A", the cell is filled with "1".

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy......we will use cell **C1** as the option:

- If **C1** is empty, use *Bar* values
- if **C1** is not empty, use *Foo* values

In **C2** enter:

**=IF($C$1="",B2,A2)**

and copy down *(column **C** will adjust based on the value in **C1**)*

Then pick a cell, say **D5**, and setup DV based on column **C**:

[image]

The drop-down list will vary as **C1** varies:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

In this case we setup the *DV* on cell **D4** to reference column **B**:

[image]

Then we install the following *Event* macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim r As Range, z As Variant, rins As Range
   Dim whereis As Range
   Set r = Intersect(Range("D4"), Target)
   Set rins = Range("B2:B10")

   If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   Set whereis = rins.Find(what:=Target.Value, After:=rins(1))
   If whereis Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   z = whereis.Offset(0, -1).Value
   Application.EnableEvents = False
      Target.Value = z
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If we now pick a letter to fill **D4**, the equivalent number will appear.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: This still doesn't work the way I want. When I select "A" in the drop down list, it should fill the cell with "1".

Comment: This is almost what I need, it just needs one little change.  My list options are in my "FooBars" tab, but I need to use the list in my "Main" tab. How would I change `Range("B2:B10")` to be something like `Range("FooBars B2:B10")`?